# Shared Session Between Two Subdomains in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have seen a number of solutions for sharing a session between two different subdomains, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Here is the setup I have:

sub1.example.com (User starts here)

sub2.example.com (PHP files are included from files in sub1)

I use the following code to start a session in the sub2 included PHP files. A session is never started directly in a file on sub1.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', 1 );
session_name( 'mySession' );
session_start();
```

I have a Javascript file that exists on sub2 that also calls PHP files in sub2. When I use session_start() in the files called by the Javascript file, though, a different session is created, which I confirmed by outputting the session IDs from the PHP files called via sub1 and the PHP files called via Javascript.

EDIT 1: Here's a better description of how the files are connected and when session_start is called:

1. User starts at index.php on sub1.
2. index.php includes preload.php that exists on sub2. Session is created here.
3. User clicks login link, which calls a function in a Javascript file from sub2.
4. Javascript calls login.php from sub2. Session is created here that does not match original session.
5. Once user successfully logs in, the page is refreshed and preload.php is called again. The session here matches the session from step 2.

EDIT 2: Here is the Javascript (and jQuery) that calls login.php:

```
function loginCheck()
{
    var name = $('#logName').val();
    var pass = $('#pass').val();
    if (pass == '' || name == '')
        return false;

    var button = $('#loginSubmit');
    $.post('SUB2ADDRESS/login.php', {name: name, pass: pass}, function(data){
        button.bind('click', function() {loginCheck(); return false;});
        if (!errorCheck(data))
            location.reload();
});
```

}

Comment: _"A session is never started directly in a file on sub1"_  what does this mean? How can you use any session in _sub1_ if you don't start one?

Comment: All of the files in sub1 include PHP files from sub2. The session_start code is in the included files from sub2.

Comment: Show us your actual JavaScript part of this then. Most likely the problem lies in there somewhere. You probably neglected to specifically instruct it to pass cookies along with cross-origin requests.

Comment: You might be onto something here. The code I am using was original just hosted on a single subdomain so I had no need to pass cookie information along. I just posted the Javascript code so hopefully you can let me know where I would do that.

Comment: Your point #2 doesn't make sense. PHP includes work via the filesystem. You definitely should not be including other PHP files via HTTP

Answer (score 0):

[CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) gave me the idea that I might need to pass the cookies along. My code may not be the best approach, but here's what I cobbled together:

I send the value of the session cookie along with my POST request to login.php.
I changed the session code to the following:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_name( 'mySession' );
if (isset($_POST['sid']))
    session_id($_POST['sid']);

session_start();
```

I had to remove the HTTPOnly flag since I needed to access the cookie information via Javascript. Ideally, I'd like to avoid doing this but I'd also like my code to work and it does now.